# Python mistake in sql3

Tags: python

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Baza.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Baza(
    Userid      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Gamename    TEXT    NOT NULL,
    Userbalance INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Gameid      INTEGER NOT NULL)
               """);
Userid = 'Userid'
Gamename = 'Gamename'
Userbalance = 'Userbalance'
Gameid = 'Gameid'

cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Baza VALUES({0}, {1}, {2},{3}").format(Userid, Gamename,Userbalance, Gameid)
conn.commit()
```

**> Mistake:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in 
import Baza
File "/home/runner/tournament/Baza.py", line 15, in 
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Baza VALUES({0}, {1}, {2},{3}").format(Userid, Gamename,Userbalance, Gameid)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input**

Comment: It makes no sense to use f-strings *and* format. But in any case, you should always use placeholders so as to avoid sql-injection attacks: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Baza VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (Userid, Gamename, Userbalance, Gameid))`. (And note that `Userid` must be an integer).